# How to calculate the volume under a parametrized surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a surface $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ where $\alpha(s,t)=(s,t,sin(t)+1)$, we rotate it by a fixed angle $\theta$ about z-axis. Then we have our new surface $\beta(s,t)=\alpha\cdot R_z(\theta)=(s\cos(\theta)+t\sin(\theta),-s\sin(\theta)+t\cos(\theta),\sin(t)+1)$. Now I want to calculate the volume under the parametrized surface $\beta$ for a rectangle in $xy$-plane. I tried to use surface integral of scalar fields but we do not have the explicit function of the surface.

Edit: If we are given a parametrized surface $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ where $\gamma(s,t)=(\gamma_1(s,t),\gamma_2(s,t),\gamma_3(s,t))$, can we always find the explicit or implicit function of this surface? If not, how can we calculate the volume under it?

Comment: One of the ways would be for the given rectangle in xy-plane, you should be able to write its bounds in terms of $u$ and $v$ or try and express $z = 1 + \sin t$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. From there on, it should be an integral over $du \ dv$ or $dx \ dy$ taking the absolute value of z-component as integrand.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for your response! I wrote $z=\sin(\sqrt(x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta)))+1$ where $(x,y,z)=\beta(s,t)$. Then, I think I can apply the formula of surface integral of scalar fields. However, if we are given an arbitrary surface $\alpha(s,t)=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$, is there a general way to calculate the volume under it?